# Why did we lose the war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

[image: this is the score we got tied up with opponents and we used only 12 attacks]
[image: this is the final result we got defeated]

I really don't understand why we lost the war. We thought we will won the war because we used less attacks.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't matter how many attacks you use in a war in this type of situation. It is the ***overall*** destruction of the enemies' bases that will be the tiebreaker.

In this case, your clan got 96 percent overall destruction while the other clan got 96.2 percent. That means the other clan wins as they got 0.2 percent more destruction that your clan did. Close, but all it needs is higher score to win.

Answer (score 7):

When there's a draw (in terms of stars earned), the winner is not selected on the number of attacks taken to get those stars, but rather on the overall destruction percentage.

Answer (score -2):

You lost the war because if the clans tie they judge it by the percent of damage made and which ever clan did a better percentage of damage wins.